# How do I check the return value of an SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

So if I have the code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$return = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

I then want to check the returned value, namely, the value of "password". Therefore, I tried this:

```
if ($return['password'] == $password)
{
    login_success();
}
```

However, that code just puts PHP into some sort of crazy loop mode where it prints out the page content again and again endlessly until I close my browser. So how do I check the return value of password against the text stored in the variable password?

Comment: what exactly your "login_success()" function do ? Code plz

Comment: is there a Redirect happening in the `login_success()` function?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. "So how do I check the return value of password against the text stored in the variable password?" -- you are already doing that. The problem is definitely with your login_success() function. Please show that code.

Comment: login_success() doesn't do anything as of now.

Comment: @Jacob, in that case you haven't posted any code relevant to the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

For check login purpose follow below code

```
  $username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

$query="select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password' ";

$result=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));

if($result>0)
{
     echo "Login Success";           
}
else
{
    echo "Login Failed";
}
```